# Debuggin in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm toying with iPhone app development. Often times I would run into runtime error and I would have no idea where the error occurs (e.g. the exact line). In console app with GCC I could at least compile with the -g flag. dump a core file and read that core file in to get to the last line that got into trouble. But how would I do that in Xcode? Build and Debug doesn't seem to have the debugging symbol loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this link and see if it helps you.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/010-Debugging_Essentials/debugging_essentials.html

Cheers,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a breakpoint by clicking the line numbers on the left-hand side of the code pane. Then the "Build and Run" button becomes "Build and Debug," and when your program reaches that point, it will stop.

From there you can click "step over," "continue," etc. to execute code one line at a time to find your errors and variable values. Hover the mouse over a variable name to find its value.